# check the nested list for symmetry

Tags: python

Tell me how to check the nested list for symmetry. For example:

```
[[[0], [2]],
 [[0], [2]],  
 [[0], [2]]]   # symmetry

[[[0], [2]],
 [[0], [2, 2] ],  
 [[0], [2]]]   # not symmetry

[[0,1,2],
 [3,4,5]]      # symmetry

[[[2, [3]]]]   # not symmetry

[[[[2], [3]]]] # symmetry
```

Comment: So, the numbers don't matter but the shape does?

Comment: `Tell me how to check the nested list for symmetry`. This site is for developers to help developers with problems they face, not to write code for them. What have you tried to solve this problem yourself (even if just pseudocode)?

Comment: Please read [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A recursive function is probably the simplest way to approach this:

```
def isSymmetric(A):
    if not isinstance(A,list): return True  # non-lists are symmetrical
    iA = (len(a) if isinstance(a,list) else -1 for a in A) # lengths
    return all(l0==ln for l0 in iA for ln in iA) and all(map(isSymmetric,A))
```

- at a given level, all lengths must be equal (i.e. first length `l0` is same as all other `ln`).
- when an item is not a list, it is considered symmetrical (for the purpose of recursion)
- when an item is a list, in addition to having all equal length items, all of its items must also be symmetrical

output:

```
s = [[[0], [2]],
    [[0], [2]],  
    [[0], [2]]]   
print(isSymmetric(s)) # True

s = [[[0], [2]],
    [[0], [2, 2] ],  
    [[0], [2]]]  
print(isSymmetric(s)) # False

s = [[0,1,2],
    [3,4,5]]      
print(isSymmetric(s)) # True

s = [[[2, [3]]]]  
print(isSymmetric(s)) # False

s = [[[[2], [3]]]] 
print(isSymmetric(s)) # True
```

*Note that this does not check for symmetry across "cousins". For example, if some sublists of the third level are not the same size but belong to different "parent list" the structure would not be detected as assymetrical. (you may want to provide an example of your expected result in such cases)*